# Visual Studio hangs when an at symbol is in the text of a continued line

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Create a new web form
Go into code behind file
Create the Page_Load event
enter the following

```
dim test as string
test = "some text " + _
"some more text with the bad symbol @"
```

When you type " right after the word with, Visual Studio will hang.

Has anyone else see this issue?

Comment: Your dev engine hangs? or your program?

Comment: Visual Studio hangs - devenv.exe *32

Comment: I just tried that and I didn't have a problem. Seems unlikely that the content of a string literal would make it fail. I could see if it was something that triggered an auto-complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a problem with VS.. probably an extension or the engine itself.. I would suggest turn off extensions, and if that doesn't work, reinstall VS? 
It shouldn't be hanging doing it..

Comment: I had to remove VS 2010 SP1 and VS 2010.  The re-install worked.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is swap out the + sign with the & character.

In VB.NET the & is the true string concatenation operator, and I've seen funny things when + is used.

Comment: Nope, I get the effect with &